# Weekly weight assignment to events using R

Tags: r, weighted-average

I am having a auction data that is irregular in nature i.e. there are weeks when only one auction on a certain day has happened and there are instances when multiple auctions have taken place on a single day. There are also events when multiple auctions have happened throughout the week.

I am trying to create a **weighted bid price** column where I am trying to apply the logic of---> bid-price(for the particular auction)*the weight of the event for the particular day and for the week.

mydata:

```
   Date    Quantity Bid_Price   No.of.Bidders
25-07-2014  75000   51.99            3
30-07-2014  75000   31.45            3
04-08-2014  75000   28.49            3
20-08-2014  150000  12.25            2
25-08-2014  75000   14.66            6
08-10-2014  75000   17.85            1
09-10-2014  75000   17.12            3
13-10-2014  75000   16.09            5
14-10-2014  75000   15.74            6
15-10-2014  75000   15.93            4
16-10-2014  150000  10.49            4
17-10-2014  75000   16.49            5
20-10-2014  75000   16.23            5
24-10-2014  75000   17.69            3
27-10-2014  75000   17.94            7
28-10-2014  75000   19.8             5
29-10-2014  75000   17.65            5
30-10-2014  75000   19.76            5
31-10-2014  75000   18.96            4
03-11-2014  150000  13.54            5
07-11-2014  75000   18.34            2
07-11-2014  75000   16.36            6
10-11-2014  75000   17.2             6
11-11-2014  75000   16.05            7
13-11-2014  75000   15.9             7
14-11-2014  75000   17.1             8
17-11-2014  75000   15.83            8
18-11-2014  75000   15.76            5
19-11-2014  75000   16.28            9
20-11-2014  75000   15.79            5
21-11-2014  75000   15.95            7
```

Initially I had proceeded with the following to calculate the weighted_bid_price, but in order to tune-up the MAPE, I am trying to achieve a weighted bid price as mentioned above.

```
mydata %>% 
  group_by(Date) %>% 
  summarise(weighted_bid_price = weighted.mean(L1_BID_PRICE, Quantity))
```

How should I proceed? Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: "the weight of the event for the particular day and for the week"-- can you clarify this? What weights do you want to apply to each bid price?

Comment: Suppose 3 events(here auctions) happened on 3 days in a particular week. So each event is having 1/5, 2/5, 3/5 (taking 5 weekdays). But if there are 2 or more events in a single day, then how to proceed with that?